# Redirect subdirectory to root URLs using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Slight tweak on some other questions/answers I found here, which didn't work for me.

My website had a subdirectory of [www.mywebsite.eu/subdirectory](http://www.mywebsite.eu/subdirectory) where *all* the website's pages were located. I have now moved all the files to [www.mywesbite.eu](http://www.mywesbite.eu). The /subdirectory has essentially been deleted.

How can I do a .htaccess redirect that makes any /subdirectory URL redirect to a URL without the subdirectory.

Here's an example:
[www.mywebsite.eu/subdirectory/webpage.html](http://www.mywebsite.eu/subdirectory/webpage.html)
now needs to be
[www.mywebsite.eu/webpage.html](http://www.mywebsite.eu/webpage.html)

Instead of doing a redirect on all the pages on my website, I'm hoping there's an easier way to just say "if someone requests a URL with /subdirectory in it, take them to exactly the same URL, just without /subdirectory at the start"

I originally tried

```
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ www.mywebsite.eu/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but that didn't work. I have this at the very start:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: I originally tried 
`RewriteRule ^dubdirectory/(.*)$ www.mywebsite.eu/$1 [L,R=301]`
but that didn't work. I have this at the very start: 
`Options +FollowSymLinks`
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteBase /`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: ok strange. I've tested it on a few links and the URL is being rewritten perfectly, but it's showing an error saying:
`The requested URL /mypage.html/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: If I enter that URL directly in my browser it loads fine.
Not sure why the trailing / is there. There must be a rule in the .htaccess doing it. Unfortunately I'm picking this website up from someone else so there is some tidying to do

Comment: Yes that means you have a faulty rule adding trailing slash to every URI. If you show your full .htaccess in question I can suggest something.

Comment: Think we've (you've) cracked it. 
`rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]`
was in my .htaccess forcing the slash. I've changed it to
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`
and the slash has gone and the RewriteRule you gave me above is working perfectly. Thanks anubhava!

Comment: Hello @anubhava I got a similar problem and I tried your rule but without success, do you have some time to see my question?

Comment: @Sophie: Is this your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69999914/dynamic-htaccess-rule-redirect-root I see an answer already there. Is that not working for you?

Comment: Yea it is, nop the arkascha rule's doesn´t work =[

Comment: The rule which I have created works fine, but I need to transform it in a dynamic, I cant create a new line each time I add a new file into the folder

Comment: I have posted an answer on that question. Try it after clearing your browser cache.