# RewriteRule for exact folder name with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Please help me on the **RewriteRule** below. I want to show the `v3.php` file for `https://example.org/signup`.

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite for signup
RewriteRule ^signup v3.php [NC,L]
```

Works. But all other requests after `/signup` like `/signups` or `https://example.org/signup/example/whatever` show the `v3.php` as well. I need that RewriteRule only for that exact folder name.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: anchor it: `RewriteRule ^signup/?$ v3.php [NC,L]`

Comment: I anchored it. Thank you, @anubhava

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^signup/?$ v3.php [NC,L]
```

Thank you, @anubhava

Comment: But why allow an optional trailing slash (ie. `/?`)? That potentially creates a [duplicate content issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75093583/add-trailing-slash-at-dynamic-htaccess) since both `/signup` and `/signup/` (2 different URLs) return the same response (a smaller problem than the one you were trying to solve initially). If you wish both URLs to be accessible then you should redirect one to the other (the "canonical" URL) - this would be handled by a separate rule.